# Normal map turns material black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, normal-map

I am trying to make a mirror with some scratches on it but when I add the normal map some parts just turn black (the stronger the normal map is the bigger the black area is). Thank you for your answers:)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution is setting your normal map image node to "Non-Color Data". You should use "Color Data" only where the image's colors matter, i.e. only when connecting to a color socket.